# div with hidden=false is still hidden

Tags: html, angular

I have some simple html code as shown here:

```
<div class="container card" hidden=false>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

As you can see the hidden tag is included and set to false. Not the string 'false' just the boolean false. Yet when run the div is still completely hidden and when I check the CSS code for why it shows that the hidden tag is giving it:
`display: none !important;` But that shouldn't be the case when `hidden` is set to false right?

Comment: If it's hard coded like this, it means you have to show it, so simply remove it ... Why would you torture yourself like this.

Comment: Also, [document yourself on how it works](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp), it might help you in the future.

Comment: I hard coded it because I wanted to set it to a variable in my typescript but it kept not working so I reduced it down to its simplest possible form to see when it started having problems.

Comment: @Kron check my answer if you want to set the value dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `hidden` use `[style.display]="hideElement?'none':'inherit'"`

Where in .ts you would set whether `hideElement` is `true` or `false`;

Alternatively create a class `.display-hide{ display:none;}` and then toggle it using

`[class.display-hide]="hideElement"`

> The hidden global attribute is a Boolean attribute indicating that the element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant. For example, it can be used to hide elements of the page that can’t be used until the login process has been completed. Browsers won’t render elements with the hidden attribute set.

I used this [link for reference](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/dont-use-hidden-attribute-angularjs-2/):

Comment: Yes perfect. Thank you not just explaining why it didn't work but providing a work around.

Comment: You obviously did not check the link i attached. Where it says why not to use the hidden attribute and what to do to solve the issue.

Comment: No I hadn't encountered that article before. Thank you for posting it though, it was quite informative on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Because hidden doesn't need a value: it either is hidden, or it isn't. The boolean you're sending is ignored. So, basically only add hidden if it should be hidden and add nothing if it should show.
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden

Answer (score 0):

The `hidden` attribute in HTML is an attribute which can't be set to any value.

For more info about the syntax, visit the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden).

Answer (score 0):

just use property binding on `hidden`

```
[hidden]=" some expression"
```

Comment: This is [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property).